# I need to get a random answer from a certain array if a condition is met

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random

I'm trying to workout a way to input either checkboxes or a dropdown list where you can check multiple items, then from the checked/selected items you click a generate button and it will produce a random answer, i have the following already but this means I have to type in the options manually in comma separated format which I don't want! any ideas on how i can achieve this? apologies if i sound stupid, im a novice coder!

```
<form method="get" action="/" onsubmit="return false;">
        <fieldset>
            <label>
                Things to pick from&#8230;<br>
                <div style="font: 12px/1.5 helvetica, sans-serif;">Comma-separated list</div>
                <textarea style="width: 400px;height: 100px;" name="things" id="things">Enter your options here..</textarea>
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Find my Food" onclick="rnd();">
            <img id="ajax-loader" src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Picking..."
        </p>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var rnd = function () {
        var loader, things;
        loader = document.getElementById('ajax-loader');
        loader.style.display = 'inline';
        things = document.getElementById('things').value;
        things = things.replace(', ', ',');
        things = things.split(',');
        setTimeout(function () {
            var thing;
            loader.style.display = 'none';
            thing = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = things[thing];
        }, 500);
    };

    </script>
    <h2>Result:</h2>
    <div id="result">Click &#8220;Find My Colour!&#8221;</div>
    </font><br />
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You don't have any checkbox or lists in your code example. For multiple choiuce lists you can check our select2 plugin

Comment: Please share your code in 'jsfiddle.net' or snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bin

https://jsbin.com/vamesafafo/1/edit?html,output

I added some default choices that you can present, maybe let the user add to it?
It just adds a checkbox for each choice, then when the button is clicked, filters out ONLY the checked boxes, then picks a random one. I left comments, feel free to improve it!
I just added a div in the html for the choices, but besides that, I just changed some javascript

```
// Add default choices here
var choices = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'kiwi'];
// cache the choices div
var choicesDiv = document.getElementById('choices');
// Add a checkbox for each choice
choices.forEach(function(choice) {
  choicesDiv.innerHTML += "<input class='things' type='checkbox' value="+choice+" /> " + choice + '<br>';
});

var rnd = function () {
    var loader, things;
    loader = document.getElementById('ajax-loader');
    loader.style.display = 'inline';
    // Slice the nodelist into a real array, and only store things that are checked
    things = slice(document.getElementsByClassName('things'))
               .filter(function(a) {return a.checked});

    setTimeout(function () {
        var thing;
        loader.style.display = 'none';
        thing = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
        // We're pulling the value stored in the html
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = things[thing].value;
    }, 500);
};

// utility for turning an array-like (like NodeList) object into an array
function slice(x) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
}
```